# Any successful profibus communications from .NET?

Tags: communication, plc, industrial

Has anyone successfully talked [profibus](http://www.profibus.com/) from a .NET application?

If you did, what device/card did you use to accomplish this, what was the application, and did you use any kind of preexisting or available code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've not used Profibus, but have used **DeviceNET** (another CAN based protocol), **Ethernet/IP** and **ControlNet** which all have similar challenges.

We've been doing this since the late 1990's and therefore rely mainly on our own generated code using off-the-shelf hardware.  The companies that have shown longevity during that period that I remember are:-

- AnyBus (HMS, [www.anybus.com](http://www.anybus.com)) we've recently started using their gateway products as we can place fieldbus interfaces close to the hardware and then communicate over normal Ethernet (usually using Ethernet/IP [www.odva.org](http://www.odva.org)).  This has the advantage of separating hardware and PC using only a network cable. The Ethernet/IP .NET classes were written by ourselves as nothing much was on the market at the time. I'm sure a quick google search would find suitable class libraries
- SST ([www.mysst.com](http://www.mysst.com)) have had fieldbus interfaces for more than a decade.  The last SST card we used for DeviceNET still only had VB6 sample code. A good selection of fieldbus support and different form-factors e.g. PC104, PCI, PMCIA
- Beckhoff/Wago ([www.beckhoff.com](http://www.beckhoff.com), [www.wago.com](http://www.beckhoff.com)) we typically use Beckhoff for the I/O more than the interface cards but again a company that has been around a long time.  They also have products that support exposing using OPC (another way for you to get I/O information without directly communicating with the hardware/devicedrivers)

I suggest not using OPC interfaces to the hardware directly (it’s OK for communication using PC (.NET)->PLC->Profibus) as you need to ensure that the control system responds to loss of control from your .NET application. I’m assuming that you are needing a profibus Master here (not a slave), so as long as your control system is intrinsically fail safe, then loss of communication should mean the control system enters an "Idle" state and therefore most of the I/O will return to the fails safe state.

We also try to ensure that we do not put safety related code in .NET.  Most of our .NET code is userinterface from a PLC, but in some places we do control the fieldbus directly but ensure hardware interlocks will prevent un-safe operation, either using safety switches/relays or a small PLC with the the task of interlocking only.  **And above all make the system fail-safe!**  Loss of comms from the .NET code should shutdown the automation to the fail-safe state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, good suggestions. I might add that you stating that everything should be fail safe is a bit redundant, as fail safe should not be the job of the PLC either. (Unless of course you are shelling out the big bucks for a Safety PLC)

Answer (score 1):

We have used Steeplechase to connect to our profibus to our automated pick system.

http://www.phoenixcontact.com/automation/32131_31909.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://libnodave.sourceforge.net