# How to read data from profibus with .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, opc

Is there any good .NET API which can be used with OPC to communicate with an PROFIBUS? Or are there any other ways to read from a .net application data from a PROFIBUS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an interface hardware I doubt you will be able to communicate directly with a profibus equipment. Have a look at Molex, they have specialized network cards interface and the relevant drivers on board. 
Link here: [Molex](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/1120110006_sd.pdf). 
Otherwhise you can also look at [Hilsher](http://www.hilscher.com/products_details_hardware.html?p_id=P_4c17837fece69&bs=8). However, all of them come with the own drivers. This topic was also dicussed some time ago on SO. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687/any-successful-profibus-communications-from-net/97659#97659).